# increasing lift in a plane by placing engine in such a way that the air coming out of it washes over the wings to create more lift

Tags: lift, efficiency

I was wondering if the engines of a plane can be placed in such a way so that the air coming out of **the engines** goes from **over** the wings so that the velocity of air over the wing is higher and more lift is generated. has this ever been done? if not than why?and what are the pros and cons of this design?

i mean something like this
[image]

Comment: Check out the [Boeing YC-14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_YC-14).

Comment: @ Fred Larson thanks. Do you know why so fewer planes like this exist?

Comment: I don't have a good answer for that, but there are folks here who may. Most likely there are tradeoffs that don't work out that well.

Comment: Related question that my give some insights: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/50127/520

Comment: Pretty much all the big turboprops, with their enormous 12 ft propellers covering nearly a 3rd of the wing span, enjoy this effect.  When flying an approach in a Dash 8 or similar, power changes have a near instantaneous effect on sink rate.

Comment: @JohnK ya but the accelerate air both above and below the wings

Comment: All the better.  Lift is mostly from the air mass below and above the wing being directed downward by the wing's passage; the "suction" of the low pressure zone is just a part of the whole effect.  Adding energy to the entire flow field will have a bigger effect than just the top flow.

Comment: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/82163/53144 answered here

Comment: I would think one reason is that jet exhausts are hot.  Aluminum alloys - to say nothing of composites! - don't really like high temperatures.